# Unable to find a valid SDK for Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I tried install UE5 to my MacBook Pro m1. When I try create new project I got this error.

> ERROR: Unable to find a valid SDK for Mac. Found Version: 13.0. Must be between 11.0.0 and 12.9.9
> If your Studio has it set up, you can run this command to find the SDK to install:
> RunUAT Turnkey -command=InstallSdk -platform=Mac -BestAvailable
> Creating makefile for MyProjectEditor (no existing makefile)
> ERROR: Platform Mac is not a valid platform to build. Check that the SDK is installed properly.

I searched on internet but I can't find anything related with this error. How can I create new project?

Comment: Please add more detail about your working flow, for example what is instruction that you follow to install UE5

Comment: @sorosh_sabz there is no specific "workflow" to get there. Install UE5 the recommended way (epic game launcher) start it, create a project, and you get this error.

Answer (score 3):

The Version 13.0 is referring to the clang version that is hosted in the Xcode.app. (clang --version)

I was able to get UE5 to compile again by downloading the older copy of Xcode 12.5.1 that includes clang version 12.0.5

(https://developer.apple.com/download/all/)

Comment: This actually won't work with macOS Monterey. 12.5.1 command line tools can't be installed on it. It might be because I have a newer version of Xcode installed. Shame.

Comment: Correct, this only worked on my Intel/BigSur Macbook. Now that I'm also working on a newer M1 with Monterey, I've needed to pull the git repo of UE5-Main and built from that where the clang requirement have been updated to handle 13.9.9

Answer (score 3):

You can also build the engine from source on branch `ue5-main`. It worked for my M1 Max Mac

Comment: Dont do that, ue5-main is an active development branch. It might be buggy or dont work at all. Instead use the release tags e.g. 5.0.3-release or 5.1.0-release